# redirect to a custom page for a list in sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have provisioned a custom list in sharepoint.

how can i redirect to a different custom page when a user selects list > new item
or edit item

Answer (score 0):

You could also edit the newform.aspx through SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have created a Custom List Template at the End of the Schema File you will have Forms Tag where you can Specify the Form to be used. you can Change that to the custom file file you want. By default it points to **Template\Pages\form.aspx** make a copy of that and update the same to Schema forms tag.